# a function that accepts a string and returns the second highest numerical digit in the input as an integer

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function that accepts a string and returns the second highest numerical digit in the input as an integer and also follow some more rules but I can not get it to work. This is what I have until now:

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {
  // Your code goes here
  var nr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
  var found_nr = [];
  var max = 0;
  var bmax = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
      if (nr[i] = input[j]) {
        found_nr.push(nr[i]);
      }
    }

  found_nr.sort();
  k = found_nr.length;
  return found_nr[k - 2];
};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("123123"));
```

secondHighestDigit("123123") should return *3*

Comment: I assume `if(nr[i] = input[j]){` should be `if(nr[i] == input[j]){` ...

Comment: Isn't 2 the second highest digit? Since 3 === 3 would make both of the 3s the greatest digits?

Comment: @JonasWilms it should be `nr[i] === input[j]`. `==` shouldn't be used anymore either you know exactly what you are doing

Comment: It already returns 3. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: *"should return 3"* - According to the code snippet in your question, it *does* return 3.  So... What are you asking?

Comment: I didn't pay attention and used `=` instead of `==`. Thank you @JonasWilms!

Comment: There are several issues with the code that really don't (to me) directly relate to the question. Assignment instead of an equality check, blindly assuming that there are elements in arrays.. Is there a better place for this kind of question? How about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? I like to help people who are learning to code but I don't think questions like this help build a good repository of coding knowledge.. and thus I suspect the down votes.. the down votes are not mine and I would really like to help..

Comment: @thomas I know what I'm doing and `===` won't work here.

Comment: If `===` won't work you should change the logic of your code. `==` does implicit casting. Use `explicit` casting with `===` to avoid surprises. In your case `nr[i] == input[j]` has the same result as `nr[i] === parseInt(input[j], 10)` but everyone sees the cast.

Comment: `"" == 0`, `false == ""`, `false == "0"`, ... are all true but `"" === 0`, `false === ""`, `false === "0"`, ... are false.

Comment: I don't understand, why you use an array of digits and why you loop over this array. Is it, to check, if a character is a digit?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input){

    var nums = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        nums.push(parseInt(input[i]));
    }
    nums.sort();
    return nums[nums.length-2];

};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("123123"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this answer:

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input) {
    // Your code goes here
    let newArray = [];

    for (let char of input) {
        if (!isNaN(char)) {
            if (!(char in newArray)) {
                newArray.push(parseInt(char));
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray.sort()[newArray.length - 2]
};
console.log(secondHighestDigit("123123adsb"));
```

I create a new array. I loop trough every character. If the character is a number, go on. (isNaN checks if it's not a number. I want the opposite so I use a !)

If the value is not in the newarray yet, push (add) it to the array

Sort the array, take the index of the array where the length of the array - 2 is.

The let is the ES6 JavaScript variable name. It is easier to use than var. You should use it if you develop for newer browsers (so not IE).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the function should return 2 as that is the **second** highest number in your list and NOT 3?

A small adjustment to @A.J Uppal's code snippet would then be this:

```js
secondHighestDigit = function(input){

    var nums = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(nums.indexOf(parseInt(input[i])) === -1)
          nums.push(parseInt(input[i]));
    }
    nums.sort();
    return nums[nums.length-2];

};

console.log(secondHighestDigit("123123"));
```